# Matrix operation using python

Tags: python, matrix

I have three set of matrix and I am required to produce the desired output. The problem is I didn't know the operation to solve the matrix.
The matrix:

```
a= [[1]
    [1]
    [0]
    [0]]

b= [[ 1. ]
   [-0.5  ]
   [-0.8660254]
   [ 0. ]]

c= [[ 1]
   [-1]
   [ 0]
   [ 0]]
```

Using the three matrix, I need to produce the result of

```
d=[[ 1]
   [0.5]
   [0.86]
   [0]]
```

So what is a?b?c?=d. I hope anyone may help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to get the desired result. First, convert the lists to arrays and then perform the following operation.

```
a= np.array([[1],[1],[0],[0]])

b= np.array([[ 1. ],[-0.5  ],[-0.8660254],[ 0. ]])

c= np.array([[ 1],[-1],[ 0],[ 0]])

d=np.array([[ 1],[0.5],[0.86], [0]])

a-b+c

array([[1.       ],
       [0.5      ],
       [0.8660254],
       [0.       ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply:
a - b + c = d